# How to add a column onto a dataframe to sum the rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I am looking to add in a column to my data frame in order to sum the total of all values in a respective row

For example:

```
1  2       Column I Want to Add

4  9                13
7  1                8
```

Comment: try with df.sum(1)?

Comment: How to find the <insert commonly used function here> of two or more columns is a common problem, please look at the duplicate listed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `df.sum(axis = 1)`, which will create a new column (not a row):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({1: [4, 7], 2: [9, 1]})

df['COLUMN I Want to Add'] = df.sum(axis = 1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   1  2  COLUMN I Want to Add
0  4  9                    13
1  7  1                     8
```

Comment: Yeah nice. Just a small comment though: the name "Row I want to Add" makes no sense. You are creating a column.

Comment: @AntonvBR xD right it makes no sense, I guess that's the OP's problem. I'll edit anyway.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! My mistake on the rows instead fo columns typo

Answer (score 0):

`df['new_col'] = df['col1'] + df['col2']`